# Apache child processes not releasing memory after allocating a huge chunk

Tags: python, django, apache, memory, wsgi

I am running Django 1.4 with WSGI on CentOS. Apache is prefork but NOT configured in Daemon mode. 8 child processes are started. I executed a database query that made the Resident Memory size of one of the child processes (the one that was serving the request) 555 MB (from 100 MB). In my code, I am fetching the rows using a pyodbc cursor. The data is not being stored anywhere, for example in a global variable.
A JSON response is sent back to the server with the serialized data. At this point, I would expect the Resident Memory to go back to 100 MB, but it remains 555 MB. 
A subsequent query DOES NOT increase the memory size (it stays at 555 MB) - which makes me hypothesize that this isn't a memory leak but the child process is simply not releasing the memory.
Also, the same sequence of steps on Windows using the Django embedded development server result in the size going to 500 MB but reverting back to below 100 MB.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you go watch:

- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/

and take note of the MaxMemFree directive in Apache which is mentioned.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxmemfree

Sounds like you may be returning one very big response as one string and with whatever Apache output filters you are using, that is causing Apache to duplicate the memory while the output filters are processing it. If you are using Apache 2.2, which has no limit for MaxMemFree, that can balloon out the size of the Apache memory pool, with the memory not being reclaimed.

If it is the size of the response which is the issue, then perhaps have the JSON encoder stream it to a file as it constructs it. Then stream the file content back.

If the memory usage is because of the database data being queried, then you would need to look at how you are doing your queries and whether you need all the data.

Comment: I will verify this tomorrow but I think you may have nailed it. I am returning a huge JSON response without streaming it.

Comment: Note that MaxMemFree may still not result in memory usage dropping as I'm not sure if Apache uses a memory allocator which can return large blocks of memory from high memory as Python can. It will at least not leave memory in the Apache memory pool and will return it to the free memory list for the whole process. Technically you can see same issue with memory not dropping in Python alone, it all really depends on the order of memory allocations. You may just have been lucky up until now and in fact that actually may be why you don't see it drop under Apache. That is order of allocations.

Comment: It is the retrieval of 2000 rows of data and creating 2000 objects out of that data which is causing it. It's not the JSON since if I retrieve the data and don't return any JSON (discard the data right after creating the objects) I still see an increase in memory.
MaxMemFree set to 256 under prefork doesn't make a difference.

I saw your PyCon talk - unrelated but seems like you recommend WSGI daemon mode with prefork MPM?